# Google APIs - How can an Authenticated user pass-on his credentials to a node server to perform operations on his behalf

Tags: node.js, browser, google-api, google-oauth, google-openid

I have a purely client-side app that lets a user authenticate himself as follows:

```
window.onSignIn = async (googleUser) => {
  const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  setProfile({ email: profile.getEmail(), name: profile.getName(), imageUrl: profile.getImageUrl() });      
};
```

I also have a node server which does a bunch a calculations. How can I pass on the credentials my user has obtained on the client to this node server, so that the node server can write the calculations results to the user's spreadsheet.

I notice that, post auth in the above code, I am getting the following:

```
{
  access_token: "..."
  expired_in: "..."
  id_token: "..."
  token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

Can I pass the above to the server to obtain a `refresh_token` indefinitely?

Comment: You are using two-legged auth which does not receive a Refresh Token. Switch to three-legged auth (which runs at the server) to obtain a Refresh Token. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: yeah thats because I started off with a pure serverless app in my mind. So is there a way to reuse the token that I have received already in the client? Afterall, its the same user and the same idp system we are hitting.

Comment: You can continue to use the Access Token until it expires - default is one hour. With a Refresh Token you can obtain a new Access Token. Without one, the user will need to reauthorize.

Comment: If the client has obtained a fresh Access Token, then you can reuse that Access Token on your server. The only gotchas are making sure you upload it securely, and that the token doesn't expire before the server has finished its work. NB This is not using a Refresh Token, which as John says, will require you rearchitecting how you do OAuth.